# Generate list of numbers with a character in between every nth numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to generate a string with the numbers from 1 to 1000 with the character `'*'` after every 5th numbers e.g.,

```
1 2 3 4 5 * 6 7 8 9 10 * 11 12 13 14 15 * 16 17 18 19 20 * …
```

Here's my attempt but as you can it is not working as expected:

```js
const insertCharacter = () => {
    let contain = [];
    let new_value;
    for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
         contain += [i];
         if (contain.length)
         contain.toString()
         let parts = contain.match(/.{0,5}/g);
         new_value = parts.join("*");
    }
    return new_value;
}
console.log(insertCharacter());
```

Comment: Apart from this solution being extremely convoluted and inefficient you haven't explained what the problem with the code is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the modulus here:

```js
var output = "";
for (var i=1; i <= 1000; ++i) {
    if (i > 1 && i % 5 == 1) output += " *";
    if (i > 1) output += " ";
    output += i;
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: the output starts with a space which might be not desired

Comment: @georg Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

Older JavaScript format version, but still valid.

The [`%` is called a Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) and is the key here.

Sample code is only counting to 50.

Edit: Changed to commented version from mplungjan.

Edit 2, for comment from georg. If you do not want a trailing Asterisk, some options:

- count to `999`, then add `1000` to the result
- use `result.substring(0,result.length-2)`

```js
var i, result = "";
for(i=1;i<51;i++){
  result += i + (i % 5 ? " " : " * ");
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `i + (i % 5 ? " " : " * ");`

Comment: if you print to `1000` as asked, there will be one extra star at the end

Comment: @georg Technically OP hasn't said anything about a trailing star. The question is to add a star after _every_ 5th character. So as far as we know this _might_ be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this code.

```js
const result = [...Array(1000)].map((val, index) => (index + 1) % 5 === 0 ? index + 1 + " *" : index + 1);
console.log(result.join(' '));
```

Comment: one extra star at the end

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want the trailing character, you could simply do:

```js
Array.from(Array(1000 / 5),
  (_, i) => (i *= 5, `${i+1} ${i+2} ${i+3} ${i+4} ${i+5}`))
    .join(' * ');
```

We don't need to iterate 1000 times: we know all the numbers already and we know we'll have 200 groups of 5 numbers each. We just need to produce those groups and join them up together.

But there are many issues with this:

- The interval is hardcoded
- The separator is hardcoded
- What if we can't split evenly the numbers?

Let say we need to insert a `|` after every 4th numbers of 10 numbers:

```
1 2 3 4 | 5 6 7 8 | 9 10
```

We have 2 groups of 4 numbers each and 1 group with the last two numbers.

*(I am going to annotate these examples so you can hopefully connect them with the full example below)*

The first two groups can be produced as follow:

```js
Array.from(Array(Math.floor(10 / 4)), (_, i) => (i*=4, [i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4].join(' ')))
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//               imax                                  tmpl
//                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                              nseq
//
//=> ['1 2 3 4', '5 6 7 8']
```

The last group with:

```js
Array(10 % 4).fill(0).map((_, i) => Math.floor(10 / 4) * 4 + i + 1).join(' ')
//    ^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//    tmax                          imax
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                  nseq
//
//=> '9 10'
```

Then you basically do:

```js
['1 2 3 4', '5 6 7 8'].concat('9 10').join(' | ')
//=> '1 2 3 4 | 5 6 7 8 | 9 10'
```

**Demo**

```js
console.log("sprintnums(10, 7, '|') -> " + sprintnums(10, 7, '|'));
console.log("sprintnums(10, 4, '|') -> " + sprintnums(10, 4, '|'));
console.log("sprintnums(10, 2, '|') -> " + sprintnums(10, 2, '|'));
console.log("sprintnums(10, 1, '|') -> " + sprintnums(10, 1, '|'));

console.log(`

  In your case:
  
${sprintnums(1000, 5, '*')}

`);
```

```html
<script>
function sprintnums(n, x, c) {
  const tmpl = Array(x).fill(0);
  const nseq = (arr, mul) => arr.map((_, i) => mul * x + i + 1).join(' ');
  const imax = Math.floor(n / x);
  const tmax = n % x;
  const init = Array.from(Array(imax), (_, mul) => nseq(tmpl, mul));
  const tail = tmax ? nseq(Array(tmax).fill(0), imax) : [];
  return init.concat(tail).join(` ${c} `);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

check this code

```js
function insertChar() {
  let res = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    res += i;
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
      res += '*'
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(insertChar());
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let str = '';
for(let i = 1; i <=1000;i++){
  str+=i;
  if(i - 1 % 5 ===0) str+='*';
}
console.log(str)
```